# Saving Array to Plist file that contains Custom Objects iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdocumentdirectory

I have a class called XYZ inheriting from NSObject and an array which contains objects of XYZ. I need to write this array to a plist file on to documents directory. After trying [array writeToFile....], I found that writeToFile fails because the array contains custom objects of XYZ class.

The possible solution to this is to convert the objects to NSData. What are the different ways of achieving this?? I found that **NSCoding** is suitable but cant understand how to use it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a very good tutorial on the [Ray Wenderlich's blog](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/how-to-save-your-app-data-with-nscoding-and-nsfilemanager) which explains how to work with the NSCoding.

Simply you just have to implement the *-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encode* and *-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder* methods in your object that respects the NSCoding protocol like that:

```
// Header
@interface AnObject: NSObject <NSCoding>

// Implementation
- (void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:ivar1 forKey:@"ivar1"];
    [encoder encodeFloat:ivar2 forKey:@"ivar2"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    ivar1 = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"ivar1"] retain];
    ivar2 = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"ivar2"] retain];
    return self;
}
```

You can also check the official documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingobjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000948-BCIHBJDE).

Comment: I am getting a memory leak in 

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder at each line. Do you know what could be the possible reason? (My iVar1 and ivar2 are strings)

Comment: Have you released them in the dealloc method?

Comment: @YannickL.hello, I want to ask is these things with `NSCoding` worth it or better stop on `NSDictionary` for code you have wrote above, for example? Is there any criteria for choosing or this is just a matter of taste? If so, how about resource costs, what is cheaper? Maybe this is a topic for a whole question but it's quiet in a theory space, so I will be very grateful of you answer here or edit your question. Thanks.

Comment: @flinth I think that's better to use the `NSCoding` protocol than a `NSDictionary` in terms of design pattern. The use of a `NSDictionary` imply the creation of a new object, and you don't have the hand over the serialization. For performance you can check this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingobjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000948-92738.

Answer (score 9):

After implementing `encodeWithCoder:` and `initWithCoder:` for the custom class here is how to write and read:

Write:

```
NSError  *error;
NSData* archiveData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:yourClassInstance];
[archiveData writeToFile:filePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
```

Read:

```
NSData *archiveData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
YourClass *yourClassInstance = (NSArray*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archiveData];
```

Comment: For deleting a particular object , How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Conforming your XYZ class to the [NSCoding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol is indeed very suitable for what you're trying to do. To do so, add the NSCoding protocol to your class's interface declaration:

```
@interface XYZ <NSCoding>
```

Then, you need implement encodeWithCoder: and initWithCoder: in your implementation. "Encode with coder" means "take your object's current state, and pack it into a generic object called an 'encoder'". "Init with coder" means "given an already-packed encoder object, configure yourself with the data packed into the encoder". In both of these methods, the 'encoder' will be an instance of [NSCoder](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCoder_Class/Reference/NSCoder.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSCoder), which has a fairly simple interface for encoding ("packing") and decoding ("unpacking") basic types.

Here's a sample implementation:

```
@implementation XYZ
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)encoder
{
    self = [self init];

    if (self)
    {
        self.myIntProperty = [encoder decodeIntForKey:@"myInt"];
    }

    return self;
}

– (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)decoder
{
    [decoder encodeInt:self.myIntProperty forKey:@"myInt"];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement two methods: `-initWithCoder:` and `-encodeWithCoder:`. Read the `NSCoding` docs; they’re pretty straight-forward methods. You basically want to encode/decode your instance variables with a key that corresponds to its name.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straight forward.  For given class `Foo`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Foo : NSObject <NSCoding> {
    NSArray* bar_;
    NSUInteger baz_;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *bar;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger baz;

@end
```

All you have to do to conform to the `NSCoding` protocol is to implement the `initWithCoder:` and `decodeWithCoder` messages:

```
#import "Foo.h"

@implementation Foo
@synthesize bar = bar_;
@synthesize baz = baz_;

#pragma mark - NSCoding

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder  {
    [encoder encodeObject:self.bar forKey:@"bar"];
    [encoder encodeInteger:self.baz forKey:@"baz"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder  {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.bar = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"bar"];
        self.baz = [decoder decodeIntegerForKey:@"baz"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc {

    [bar_ release];
    [super dealloc];    
}

@end
```