# Saving NSMutableArray to plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I just finished Apple's ["Start Developing iOS Apps Today"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/ThirdTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH10-SW1) guide.

On the end of this tutorial I have basic ToDo App which keeps data in `NSMutableArray`. I want to put this data into plist. I found the solution on stackoverflow but it didn't work in my case.

```
- (void) writeToPlist: (NSString*)fileName withData:(NSMutableArray *)data
{
     NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *finalPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

 [data writeToFile:finalPath atomically: YES];
}
```

It should save plist file in documents folder of my ios device (acctually it is iOS simulator). Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What kind of objects are in your array?

Comment: Why and how does it not work?

Comment: NSString, BOOL and NSDate

Comment: It doesn't save plist file in 'documents' of iDevice

Comment: It can't contain `BOOL`. You can't put primitive types in an array.

Comment: What happens if you replace the last line in your method with `[@[@"test"] writeToFile:finalPath atomically:YES]`?

Comment: If this doesn't write a plist to the documents folder, either your path is wrong, or you're looking at the wrong place.

Comment: it's workinh then. So I will try change BOOL for something else

Comment: I'm affraid it not working even if I change BOOL for NSNumber and oparate on 0-1

Comment: Does the array actually contain separate `NSString`, `NSDate`, and `NSNumber` objects or does it contain classes with those types of properties? You can't store custom classes in a plist unless you archive them to `NSData` objects.

Comment: You might be right. So I will try put it into NSData. Is there some quick way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving an NSDictionary of NSArrays of custom objects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4235485)

Comment: @Davgranded What do you mean that I "might" be right? Don't you know? Do you have custom objects in the array or not? It's important.

Comment: Sorry. What I wanted to say was: "You are right" :) I have custom objects in my array. Diana Shumskaya gives answer below but I don't get it :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving Array to Plist file that contains Custom Objects iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111965/saving-array-to-plist-file-that-contains-custom-objects-iphone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Property list files can only store basic data types and cannot contain custom objects. 
You need to implement the methods of protocol `<NSCoding>` for the object XYZToDoItem:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder;
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder;
```

and then write data:

```
NSData *savedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:data];
[savedData writeToFile:finalPath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
```